# Dynamic update sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im building a dynamic sql update statement. This statement will update an unknown number of columns. Im looking for a clever way to set the commas between the columns in the update-statement correct.

```
DECLARE @UpdateSQL nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET '
WHILE (somecondition)
BEGIN
    IF (someothercondition)
        SET @UpdateSQL = @UpdateSQL + @ColNameVar + ' = ' @ColNameVar + ',' --How to set this comma only on columns that are not the last??
END
```

There is ofcourse more building to do with this updateSQL, but this is the only relevant part for my question.

One important note is that the last run of the while-loop is not necessarly putting in a new column in the update, so i could not use that as a check.

Any ideas?

Using SQL Server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your loop, strip the last character?

```
SET @UpdateSQL = LEFT(@UpdateSQL, LEN(@UpdateSQL) - 1)
```

Change the position of the ',' to the FRONT of the appended code, but don't set it for the first one...

```
DECLARE @UpdateSQL nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET ', @comma NVARCHAR(2) = ' '
WHILE (somecondition)
BEGIN
    IF (someothercondition)
    BEGIN
        SET @UpdateSQL = @UpdateSQL + @comma + @ColNameVar + ' = ' @ColNameVar
        SET @comma     = ', '
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks! You are all correct. So its difficult to choose who to mark as correct... :S

Answer (score 0):

You can remove last character `,` after while loop as below:

```
DECLARE @UpdateSQL nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET '
WHILE (somecondition)
BEGIN
    IF (someothercondition)
        SET @UpdateSQL = @UpdateSQL + @ColNameVar + ' = ' @ColNameVar + ','
              --How to set this comma only on columns that are not the last??
END
SET @UpdateSQL  = LEFT(@UpdateSQL , LEN(@UpdateSQL)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are all correct. So its difficult to choose who to mark as correct... :S

Answer (score 0):

Since the string might *not* end with a comma, try this:

```
if right(@UpdateSQL, 1) = ','
begin
    set @UpdateSQL = left(@UpdateSQL, len(@UpdateSQL) - 1)
end
```

Comment: I'm trusting that the OP already tests that so as to avoid executing `UPDATE MYTABLE SET ` on its own :)

Comment: Thanks! You are all correct. So its difficult to choose who to mark as correct... :S

Answer (score 0):

There'a always almost a better way to do things than dynamic SQL... tables have a finite number of columns, even if the update is dynamic. In this case, write a complete UPDATE statement, with conditional SET clauses:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET Col1 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Col1, '') = '' THEN Col1 ELSE @Col1 END,
Col2 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Col2, '') = '' THEN Col1 ELSE @Col2 END,
Col3 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Col3, '') = '' THEN Col1 ELSE @Col3 END,
Col4 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Col4, '') = '' THEN Col1 ELSE @Col4 END
WHERE Blah = 'blah'
```

The exact clause for your statements may be different - you may be able to replace the CASE statement with an ISNULL() or COALESCE() to make it easier to manage.

This means that the query will be cached, execution will be faster (though that's negligable), but most importantly, the code will be much easier to read and debug.

Comment: An advantage of this method over the dynamic sql that you didn't mention is that dynamic sql is more prone to sql injections